# Processing Multiple Comma Separated Values in Rails Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a field in an app that currently allows admins of Groups to invite other Users (to the group).  It works for a single value, but I'm wondering how to adjust it so that it allows the admin to enter multiple Users separated by commas into the field.

```
# form in view
<%= form_tag({:controller => "group_members", :action => "invite_user"}, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'group_id', @group.id%>
  <%= text_field_tag :user_name %>
  <%= submit_tag "Invite" %>
<% end %>

# group_members_controller
def invite_user
  @user = User.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
  @group_member = GroupMember.create!(:status=>"invited", :user_id=>@user.id, :group_id => params[:group_id], :token => SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "#{@user.user_name} has been invited to your group"
end
```

Comment: Are you using autocomplete or you are writing the use id?

Comment: writing the user_name, sorry, the text_field_tag should be named :user_name instead of :user_id

Comment: Consider using autocomplete, because is hard to write all names correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let `params[:user_name]` be a comma seperated list of users and parse it in invite_user:

```
@users = params[:user_name].split(/,\s*/).
```

This would split `params[:user_name]` into an array, splitting on a comma followed by zero or more whitespace characters. Turning `"Joe, John,     Marry,Ann"` into `["Joe", "John", "Marry", "Ann"]`.

You could then do the following still in invite user:

```
@users.each do |username|
    @user = User.find_by_user_name(params[username])
    @group_member = GroupMember.create!(:status=>"invited", :user_id=>@user.id, 
                                        :group_id => params[:group_id], 
                                        :token => SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)

end

redirect_to :back, notice: "my_message"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "group_members", :action => "invite_users"}, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'group_id', @group.id%>
  <%= text_field_tag :users %>
  <%= submit_tag "Invite" %>
<% end %>

# group_members_controller
def invite_users
  user_names = params[:users].split(/,\s*/)
  users = User.where(name: user_names)
  group_id = params[:group_id]

  @users.each do |user|
    GroupMember.create!(:status=>"invited", :user_id=>user.id, :group_id => group_id, :token => SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)
  end

  redirect_to :back, notice: "Users have been invited to your group"
end
```